# Count() function in vimscript

Tags: vim

I was reading the .vimrc from spf13-vim on github, and there was something I didn't understand:

```
" Snippets & AutoComplete
    if count(g:spf13_bundle_groups, 'snipmate')
        Bundle 'garbas/vim-snipmate'
        Bundle 'honza/vim-snippets'
        " Source support_function.vim to support vim-snippets.
        if filereadable(expand("~/.vim/bundle/vim-snippets/snippets/support_functions.vim"))
            source ~/.vim/bundle/vim-snippets/snippets/support_functions.vim
        endif
    elseif count(g:spf13_bundle_groups, 'neocomplcache')
        Bundle 'Shougo/neocomplcache'
        Bundle 'Shougo/neosnippet'
        Bundle 'honza/vim-snippets'
    elseif count(g:spf13_bundle_groups, 'neocomplete')
    Bundle 'Shougo/neocomplete.vim.git'
        Bundle 'Shougo/neosnippet'
        Bundle 'honza/vim-snippets'
    endif
```

What does the `count()` function do here?

Comment: Please learn to use the help, it's good: "What does the `count()` function do?" → `:h count()`. Problem solved.

Answer (score 1):

check if the item (snipmate or neocomplcache...) exists in the `g:spf13_bundle_groups`.

Answer (score 1):

`:help count()` tells you:

> Return the number of times an item with value {expr} appears
>   in |List| or |Dictionary| {comp}.

So this counts how often the value (e.g. `'snipmate'`) occurs in the List variable `g:spf13_bundle_groups`. The resulting number is then interpreted as a Boolean (0 = false, everything else = true).

A more canonical (and maybe a little bit faster) way would be to use `index()` instead:

```
if index(g:spf13_bundle_groups, 'snipmate') != -1
    ...
```